# too many indices for array with matplotlib subplots

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to plot 2 different data sets but I don't know how to fix the subplot (if i put 2,2 it works but if i try anything else it gives me an error)

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)

axs[0,1].plot(adj_close['SOL-USD'])
axs[2,1].set_title('SOL')

plt.show()
```

error:

```
----> 6 axs[0,0].plot(adj_close['SOL-USD'])
      7 axs[0,0].set_title('SOL')
      8 axs[0,1].plot(adj_close['ETH-USD'])

TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not subscriptable

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [356], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 #ploting the histogram
      2 fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(16,8),gridspec_kw ={'hspace': 0.2, 'wspace': 0.1})
----> 3 axs[0,0].hist(returns['SOL-USD'], bins=50, range=(-0.2, 0.2))
      4 axs[0,0].set_title('SOL')
      5 axs[1,0].hist(returns['ETH-USD'], bins=50, range=(-0.2, 0.2))

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

what it currently looks like with subplot 2,2:
[image: what it currently looks like with subplot 2,2]

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre], and make sure to show 1) code that someone else can copy and paste, without changing anything, to reproduce the exact problem (and not something else); 2) a complete error message *that corresponds to the code shown*. In the example, it's not clear whether `axs` is a typo for `axes`, or meant to refer to a different variable not shown; and the error message clearly shows code that doesn't reflect the code in the example. (Also, please try to **ask a question** instead of just showing code and an error.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel hi there, i don't think axs is a typo because when i change  `plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)` to `plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)` it gets graphed :(

Comment: Where does `axs` get defined, then?

Comment: `fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(16,8),gridspec_kw ={'hspace': 0.2, 'wspace': 0.1})`

Comment: sorry i tried to go in and edit it but i think i pasted the wrong code

Comment: @KarlKnechtel f

Comment: in the future, please edit your question to include the correct code rather than posting updates in the comments. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is going on here is that `matplotlib.pyplot.subplots()` creates an array of one dimension for axes in fig if nrows or ncols is equal to 1. You can see this by displaying the variable in your current workspace.

`>>> fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)`

`>>> axes`

`array([<AxesSubplot:>, <AxesSubplot:>], dtype=object)`

That is why an index error appears when trying to call more than one. For more documentation, here is the site to the function [matplotlib.pyplot.subplots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html)

Comment: Ew. Unfortunate design, IMO. `Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.`

Comment: agreed. it's not a great default

Comment: Answer #2 ever and you fired off something high quality this fast? I'm impressed :) welcome to stack overflow!

Answer (score 1):

See the [`matplotlib.pyplot.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) documentation. There is an optional argument `squeeze`, default `True`:

> **`squeeze`** : *bool, default: True*
> If True, extra dimensions are squeezed out from the returned array of Axes:
>
> - if only one subplot is constructed (nrows=ncols=1), the resulting single Axes object is returned as a scalar.
> - for Nx1 or 1xM subplots, the returned object is a 1D numpy object array of Axes objects.
> - for NxM, subplots with N>1 and M>1 are returned as a 2D array.
>
> If False, no squeezing at all is done: the returned Axes object is always a 2D array containing Axes instances, even if it ends up being 1x1.

So, with the default of `squeeze=True`, axes will be a different shape depending on your arguments:

- `plt.subplots(1, 1)` --> single `Axis` object
- `plt.subplots(1, n)` --> 1-dimensional vector of `Axis` objects
- `plt.subplots(n, 1)` --> 1-dimensional vector of `Axis` objects
- `plt.subplots(n, m)` --> 2-dimensional array of `Axis` objects